# NameError: name 'labels' is not defined

Tags: python

I am following line by line example from Building Machine Learning Systems with Python(Richart,Pedro Coelho) book.

After importing iris data sets,we want to extract ones with Setosa

```
data = load_iris()
features = data['data']
plength = features[:, 2]
# use numpy operations to get setosa features
is_setosa = (labels == 'setosa')
```

I got this

```
>>> is_setosa = (labels == 'setosa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'labels' is not defined
```

I guess that is typo so I tried

```
>>> is_setosa = plenght(labels == 'setosa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'plenght' is not defined
>>> is_setosa = plength(labels == 'setosa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'labels' is not defined
>>> is_setosa = data(labels == 'setosa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'labels' is not defined
```

What should I do now?
How can I inspect data object?

```
>>> data.labels
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 58, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: labels
>>> data.dtypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/milenko/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 58, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: dtypes
```

This is the relevant part of the description

```
- class:\n                - Iris-Setosa\n                - Iris-Versicolour\n                - Iris-Virginica\n    :
```

Comment: It's clear enough, the variable `labels` is not defined!

Comment: Chances are you can do something like data['labels'] or data.labels... inspect the data object

Comment: You wan't a boolean value in your `is_setosa` variable. For that you're doing a comparison between `labels == 'setosa'`. Now `labels` isn't defined before. Mind writing a declaration above like `labels=""`?

Comment: @FLab Take a look at my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just type `data` into the iPython console you will see a description of the dataset. In particular there are two fields: `data['target']` contains numerical labels {0, 1, 2} which corresponds to the names reported in `data['target_names']`, i.e. {'setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'}.

So you can probably define `labels` as follows:

```
labels = map(lambda x: dict(enumerate(data['target_names']))[x], data['target'])
```

Answer (score 0):

it mainly beacause the code in the book is lack of defining "labels". Based on the context, add the following codes:

```
target = data['target']
target_names = data['target_names']
labels=np.array([target_names[i] for i in target])
```